# ManyToOne is not updating with cascade

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using `hibernate` to update `ManyToOne` relationship, but it is not updating child class.

```
 class People{
     @Id
     @Column(name = "People_id")
     @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
     @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
     private String id;
     @NotNull
     @Size(max = 45)        
     @Column(name = "phone", length = 45, nullable = false)
     private String phone;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="regions_id")
     private Regions regionsid;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
     @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
     private Role role_id;
 }

 class Role {

     @Id
     @Column(name = "Role_id")
     @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
     @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
     private String id;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="regions_id")
     @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
     private Regions regions_id;
 }

 public class Regions implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;
 }
```

When i am saving people using :-

```
people.getRole_id().setRegions_id(people.getRegions_id());
    People result = peopleRepository.saveAndFlush(people);
```

Is is not updating the region table with region code.

I am not sure if cascade is define correct or not.

Can you please guide me how to correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

with your code:

```
people.getRole_id().setRegions_id(people.getRegions_id());
People result = peopleRepository.saveAndFlush(people);
```

You updated **regions_id** column in **Role** table, but **not** the region table with region code.

Could you explain what you wish to do?

Comment: whatever region people has i am trying to put that region in role table as well, as both table have this region id column.